# How to flatten a 'friendship' model within User model in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I recently came across a number of articles pointing out to flatten the data for NoSQL databases. Coming from traditional SQL databases I realized I am replicating a SQL db bahaviour in GAE. So I started to refactor code where possible.

We have e.g. a social media site where users can become friends with each other.

```
class Friendship(ndb.Model):
   from_friend = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
   to_friend = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
```

Effectively the app creates a friendship instance between both users.

```
friendshipA = Friendship(from_friend = UserA, to_friend = userB)
friendshipB = Friendship(from_friend = UserB, to_friend = userA)
```

How could I now move this to the actual user model to flatten it.  I thought maybe I could use a StructuredProperty. I know it is limited to 5000 entries, but that should be enough for friends.

```
class User(UserMixin, ndb.Model):
     name = ndb.StringProperty()
     friends = ndb.StructuredProperty(User, repeated=True)
```

So I came up with this, however User can't point to itself, so it seems. Because I get a `NameError: name 'User' is not defined`

Any idea how I could flatten it so that a single User instance would contain all its friends, with all their properties?

Comment: You could use a `ListProperty` with strings for the ids of all the friends for a user. It's not very OOP but it's easy and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a StructuredProperty that references itself.  Also, use of StructuredProperty to store a copy of `User` has additional problem of needing to perform a manual cascade update if a user ever modifies a property that is stored.

However, as KeyProperty accept String as `kind`, you can easily store the list of Users using KeyProperty as suggested by @dragonx.  You can further optimise read by using `ndb.get_multi` to avoid multiple round-trip RPC calls when retrieving friends.

Here is a sample code:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
     name = ndb.StringProperty()
     friends = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="User", repeated=True)

userB = User(name="User B")
userB_key = userB.put()

userC = User(name="User C")
userC_key = userC.put()

userA = User(name="User A", friends=[userB_key, userC_key])
userA_key = userA.put()

# To retrieve all friends
for user in ndb.get_multi(userA.friends):
    print "user: %s" % user.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a KeyProperty that stores the key for the User instance.

Comment: But that is like a ForeignKey style. I would have a collection of friend's keys, but not their names etc.  You know what I mean? It is not properly flat yet...

Comment: And yet a (repeated) KeyProperty is what you should do.  The idea of having a single User instance containing copies of all its friends just doesn't work, since it contains copies that won't be updated when any of the friends updates their properties.